# Rails4 - How to inherit from RocketPants::Base while writing API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rocketpants

I am trying to create API for my Rails app. I have these following controllers.
[image]

I have the following inheritance

/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb

```
module Api
  class ApiController < ApplicationController
  # logic
```

/app/controllers/api/home_page_controller.rb

```
class Api::HomePageController < Api::ApiController
   # logic
```

/app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb

```
class Api::UsersController < Api::ApiController
   # logic
```

/app/controllers/api/sessions_controller.rb

```
class Api::SessionsController < Api::ApiController
   # logic
```

/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # logic
```

When I try to inherit from RocketPants::Base like the following as mentioned in https://github.com/Sutto/rocket_pants

/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb

```
module Api
  class ApiController < RocketPants::Base
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
     # logic
```

I get errors like this

```
Started POST "/api/sessions" for 104.155.204.133 at 2015-04-21 22:59:56 +0000
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `protect_from_forgery' for Api::ApiController:Class):
  app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:11:in `<class:ApiController>'
  app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:2:in `<module:Api>'
  app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/api/sessions_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta4/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta4/lib/action_dispatch/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (40.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta4/lib/action_dispatch/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (19.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta4/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (266.2ms)
104.155.204.133 - - [21/Apr/2015:22:59:57 +0000] "POST /api/sessions HTTP/1.1" 404 97164 1.1316
```

I have added the gem and executed bundle install.

Gemfile

```
gem 'rocket_pants', '~> 1.10.0'
```

Can someone kindly guide me how to add rocketpants?

Comment: That error is pretty straight forward - RocketPants::Base does not define `protect_from_forgery `.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and instead ask: "How do I protect against CSRF with RocketPants?"

Comment: @papirtiger I do not get any error when I do not use RocketPants. I am getting the error when I try to add RocketPants gem and follow the steps mentioned in the gem documentation.

Comment: Thats because you were inheriting from [`ActionController::Base` which does define `protect_from_forgery `](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the skip_before_filter and protect_from_forgery lines from controller. All errors are gone.